# Checking Plays store version with current version and show update dialog

Tags: android

I have published one app on playstore and now i want to dhow update dialog when new apk is available on playstore.

I get latest version and current version

Till now i tried following code

```
      if (latestVersion != null && !latestVersion.isEmpty()) {
        if (Float.valueOf(currentVersion) < Float.valueOf(latestVersion)) {
            update_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            update_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_dialog);
            update_dialog.setCancelable(false);
            TextView dd = (TextView) update_dialog.findViewById(R.id.udata);
            Button update = (Button) update_dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
            c_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/CaviarDreams_Italic.ttf");
            dd.setTypeface(c_font);
            update.setTypeface(c_font);
            update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.this.anything.unknown"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            update_dialog.show();
        } else {

        }
    }
```

it work fine but now i want to set version 1.2.0(Two dots).then how to check 1.0(one dot) with 1.2.0(two dots)

How to compare 1.2.0 and 1.0 or 1.2.0 and 1.2.1

Comment: you can use FCM notification when you want to notify users to update app and according to notification you can also manage version name and compare it with current version name of app and store notification data in shared preference and everytime you can check version name with current version name 
That's it !!!

Comment: How can you get the version from google play store?

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to compare `versionCode` not `versionName`. You will get it in `Integer` form.

Comment: Simply, you can't. check my comment on your question. 
But you can maintain it on your own server. when you update the app on google play store , update your version on your own server. and you just need to check on your server every time you open the app when network enable. and perform the action.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, the easiest way is to convert the version by splitting the version with dots into array & comparing each array elements.

```
String currentVersion = "1.1";
String latestVersion = "1.2.3";
String[] currentVersionArray = currentVersion.split("\\.");
String[] latestVersionArray = latestVersion.split("\\."); 

int minLength = Math.min(currentVersionArray.length, latestVersionArray.length);
boolean isUpgradeAvailable = false;

for(int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
    if(Integer.parseInt(currentVersionArray[i]) < Integer.parseInt(latestVersionArray[i])) {
        isUpgradeAvailable = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!isUpgradeAvailable && minLength != latestVersionArray.length)
    isUpgradeAvailable = true;
```

Comment: would 2.0 be higher than 1.0.1 in your algorithm? 20<101

Comment: @LeosLiterak  good catch +1 ur comment.. but he need to define it as 2.0.0 i think. ;)

Comment: Ya thanks for recommendation..I will take care to define version code

Comment: @LeosLiterak Thanks for the case. Somehow missed it.

Comment: @sourabhbans even if I define it in 2.0.0 in previous solution, it will fail if the current version is something like 1.2.11 which will be greater than 2.0.0 ;)

Comment: @sJy thats the matter of formatting in that case.. then you have to make it  `2.0.00` .

Comment: We use XYYZZBB pattern in our app -  e.g 2.0.1 build 03.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Yes. At the same time OP has his specific pattern for which he is looking the answer. "How to compare 1.2.0 and 1.0 or 1.2.0 and 1.2.1"

Comment: The best solution is to change their pattern. I had same trouble few years ago and this is the way how to do it correctly.